# Tracking progress of 'Publish Web' action in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm using the "Publish Web" action to deploy my web application. Is there a way to track it (see the progress) of this action?

Does the [command line version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776635/replicate-vs2008-publish-web-site-from-command-line) report progress? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe output windows shows you progress, it is not a tradiotional progress bar but it tells you each step and gives you a folder by folder output of the upload progress.