# VS2010 Web Publish command line version of File System deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, msdeploy, web-publishing, msbuild-wpp

Folks,

In a nutshell, I want to replicate this dialog:
[image]

It's a Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net MVC project.  If I execute this command, I get all the files I want, including the transformed web.configs in the "C:\ToDeploy" directory.

I want to replicate this on the command line so I can use it for a QA environment build.

I've seen various articles on how to do this on the command line for Remote Deploys, but I just want to do it for File System deploys.

I know I could replicate this functionality using nAnt tasks or rake scripts, but I want to do it using this mechanism so I'm not repeating myself.

I've investigated this some more, and I've found these links, but none of them solve it cleanly:

- [VS 2008 version, but no Web.Config transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776635/replicate-vs2008-publish-web-site-from-command-line)
- [Creates package, but doesn't deploy it..do I need to use MSDeploy on this package?](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/web-packaging-creating-web-packages.html)
- [Deploys package after creating it above...does the UI really do this 2 step tango?](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-packaging-installing-web-packages.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok, finally figured this out.

The command line you need is:

```
msbuild path/to/your/webdirectory/YourWeb.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False
```

You can change where the project outputs to by adding a property of `outdir=c:\wherever\` in the /p: section.

This will create the output at:

```
path/to/your/webdirectory/obj/Debug/Package/PackageTmp/
```

You can then copy those files from the above directory using whatever method you'd like.

I've got this all working as a ruby rake task using [Albacore](http://albacorebuild.net/).  I am trying to get it all done so I can actually put it as a contribution to the project.  But if anyone wants the code before that, let me know.

Another wrinkle I found was that it was putting in Tokenized Parameters into the Web.config.  If you don't need that feature, make sure you add:

```
/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this copies the entire package. I think you'll need to use MS Web Deploy to only copy changed files.

Comment: For completness, the OutDir property must end with a trailing slash (MSBuild errors out otherwise). So your suggestion should be `outdir=c:\wherever\ `.

Comment: Also, instead of `/p:DeployOnBuild=True` you could just use the Package target: `/t:Package`. Works for me, plus both `PackageAsSingleFile` and `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings` parameters are respected as well.

Comment: @Jakub I updated the answer to reflect the OutDir comment, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I thought I'd post a another solution that I found, I've updated this solution to include a log file.

This is similar to [Publish a Web Application from the Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076971/publish-a-web-application-from-the-command-line), but just cleaned up and added log file. also check out original source http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild

**Create an MSBuild_publish_site.bat (name it whatever) in the root of your web application project**

```
set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set destPath=C:\Publish\MyWebBasedApp\

:: clear existing publish folder
RD /S /Q "%destPath%"

call %msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe  MyWebBasedApp.csproj "/p:Configuration=Debug;PublishDestination=%destPath%;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False" /t:PublishToFileSystem /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Manual_MSBuild_Publish_LOG.log

set msBuildDir=
set destPath=
```

**Update your Web Application project file MyWebBasedApp.csproj by adding the following xml** under the `<Import Project=` tag

```
<Target Name="PublishToFileSystem" DependsOnTargets="PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder">
<Error Condition="'$(PublishDestination)'==''" Text="The PublishDestination property must be set to the intended publishing destination." />
    <MakeDir Condition="!Exists($(PublishDestination))" Directories="$(PublishDestination)" />

    <ItemGroup>
        <PublishFiles Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(PublishFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PublishFiles->'$(PublishDestination)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SkipUnchangedFiles="True" />
</Target>
```

this works better for me than other solutions.

Check out the following for more info:

1) http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild

2) [Publish a Web Application from the Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076971/publish-a-web-application-from-the-command-line)

3) [Build Visual Studio project through the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669765/build-visual-studio-project-through-the-command-line/5669820#5669820)

Answer (score 1):

My solution for **CCNET** with the **Web.config transformation**:

```
<tasks>
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>E:\VersionesCC\Trunk_4\SBatz\Gertakariak_Orokorrak\GertakariakMS\Web</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>GertakariakMSWeb2.vbproj</projectFile>
        <targets>Build</targets>
        <timeout>600</timeout>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
        <buildArgs>
            /noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release /v:diag
            /p:DeployOnBuild=true
            /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
            /p:DeployTarget=Package
            /p:_PackageTempDir=E:\Aplicaciones\GertakariakMS2\Web
        </buildArgs>
        </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

Answer (score 1):

On VS2012 and above, you can refer to existing [publish profiles on your project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx) with msbuild 12.0, this would be equivalent to right-click and publish... selecting a publish profile ("MyProfile" on this example):

```
msbuild C:\myproject\myproject.csproj "/P:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=MyProfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution for Visual Studio 2012: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387814/2164198

However, it works with no Visual Studio installed at all! (see **UPDATE**).
I didn't checked yet whether one can get all needed stuff from Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web installation.

Answer (score -1):

A complete msbuild file with inspiration from CubanX

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Publish">
        <RemoveDir Directories="..\build\Release\Web\"
                     ContinueOnError="true" />        
       <MSBuild Projects="TheWebSite.csproj"
                Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
                Properties="Configuration=Release;WebProjectOutputDir=..\build\Release\Web;OutDir=..\build\Release\Web\bin\"
        />  
    </Target>
    <Target
        Name="Build"
        DependsOnTargets="Publish;">
    </Target>   
</Project>
```

This places the published website in the Web..\build\Release folder