# Publish ASP.NET MVC 2 application from command line and Web.config transformations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

Good day!

I've found this solution here: [VS2010 Web Publish command line version of File System deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029541/vs2010-web-publish-command-line-version-of-file-system-deploy)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe 
.\MyProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;outdir=c:\_OuputDir\
```

But it seems that Web.config transformations are not performed.

May be there is better\cleaner way to duplicate "Publish Web" VS2010 dialog?

**Update: The answer which is marked is the shortest command-line to perform publish, that I've found so far. Web.config transformations ARE applied, but connection strings are treated differently, here is a [description\workaround](http://forums.asp.net/p/1569934/4043217.aspx)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work (which I found [here](http://pattersonc.com/blog/2010/07/15/visual-studio-2010-publish-command-from-msbuild-command-line/)):

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package;_PackageTempDir=..\publish
```

However, it gave me the following error when I tried to run it (which I'm still working to fix):

> C:\[path]\[config]\csautoparameterize\original\web.config(40): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: It works for me to make a publish (that's the shortest and the cleanest way to get output to separate folder), but Web.config is not transformed, here how my connection string looks after publish `<add name="ExampleConnectionString" connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_ExampleConnectionString-Web.config Connection String_0)" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Comment: update: all my transformations except connection strings are processed!!! Is there any way to get it to work for connection strings? It seems to be by design: http://forums.asp.net/p/1569934/4043217.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from: http://ashwaniksharma.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AD160FFA5932F17E!206.entry

```
MSBuild .\MyProject.csproj /t:TransformWebConfig;/p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;outdir=c:\_OuputDir\
```

Comment: It looks like it should done what I'm looking for, but I've got the following message and nothing changes: `TransformWebConfigCore:
Skipping target "TransformWebConfigCore" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.`

Comment: It seems the transformed web.config is placed under obj\<config name>\TransformWebConfig\transformed in the MVC app folder when you do this command. Not sure what ties this together and produces the final package as publish in Visual Studio does.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for *CCNET* with the *Web.config transformation*:

```
<tasks>
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>E:\VersionesCC\Trunk_4\SBatz\Gertakariak_Orokorrak\GertakariakMS\Web</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>GertakariakMSWeb2.vbproj</projectFile>
        <targets>Build</targets>
        <timeout>600</timeout>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
        <buildArgs>
            /noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release /v:diag
            /p:DeployOnBuild=true
            /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
            /p:DeployTarget=Package
            /p:_PackageTempDir=E:\Aplicaciones\GertakariakMS2\Web
        </buildArgs>
        </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

Comment: The parameter "/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false" was new for me. I've added it to the MSBUILD commandline and it did the trick.