# Publish ASP.NET web site from command-line bat file, the ultimate .bat file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, msbuild

There are a number of questions here on SO about how to publish ASP.NET web site from command-line (including my own [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381864/publish-asp-net-mvc-2-application-from-command-line-and-web-config-transformatio/5099253#5099253)), but none of them get me to the solution I want:

- Single output folder as I specified
- Applied Web.config transformations

I'm getting close to something that works for me, but there are still a couple of issues.
Here is what I have so far:

```
SET TEMP_PATH=c:\_MyProject\
SET DEST_PATH=%TEMP_PATH%_Output\
SET CSPROJ_PATH=.\MyProject\MyProject.csproj
SET CONFIGURATION=Release
SET LOG_FILE=MyProjectDeploy.log

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ^
%CSPROJ_PATH% ^
/p:Configuration=%CONFIGURATION%;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False ^
/property:OutDir=%TEMP_PATH% ^
/property:WebProjectOutputDir=%DEST_PATH% ^
/l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=%LOG_FILE%
```

But my script still has these problems:

- The version with one Web.config with applied transformation is deep inside folder structure: `C:\_MyProject\_PublishedWebsites\MyProject_Package\Archive\Content\C_C\<Long path that replicate my folder structure>\obj\Release\Package\PackageTemp\` The problem that path to the probject is included here, so it cat vary from developer to developer.
- The version which is located in `%DEST_PATH%` is what I need but without Web.config transformations

Comment: Web Site or Web Application Project?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application Project (as default templates), not a web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ultimate solution exists:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452664/118810

It works for solutions too.