# Build Visual Studio project through the command line

Tags: c#, build, windows-server-2008, command, cmd

I am running an ASP.NET website from a Windows Server 2008 installation, and I like to edit the pages through the command line since I ssh into the server.

I installed [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) on the server so that I can edit the files easily. If I edit HTML and CSS and .aspx pages, the updates are successful. But if I want to edit source code I would have to rebuild the project. Rebuilding the project recompiles everything nicely and updates the copy on the web. This is a development server so updates to everything is fine since no one sees this server.

How can I build the project through the command line to update the source code and build on the server?

The project is written in C# and the files are all in the `wwwroot` folder so no file moving needs to occur after a build.

Answer (score 52):

Create a .bat file called:
Manual_MSBuild_ReleaseVersion.bat

Put this in the .bat file.

```
REM you'll have to find the "latest" version of where msbuild.exe resides on your machine.. here are some popular versions/locations
REM set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
REM set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
REM set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
REM set msBuildDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin
set msBuildDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

call "%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe"  MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Manual_MSBuild_ReleaseVersion_LOG.log
set msBuildDir=
```

You can build a .sln file or a .csproj file.
MySolution.sln or MyProject.csproj

See *[How to: Use MSBuild to Create a Web Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547591.aspx)* for more information.

You can take it one step further:

```
rd .\BuildResults /S /Q
md .\BuildResults
rd .\MyProject\Bin\Release  /S /Q

REM you'll have to find the "latest" version of where msbuild.exe resides on your machine.. here are some popular versions/locations
REM set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
REM set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
REM set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
REM set msBuildDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin
set msBuildDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
call "%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe"  MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Manual_MSBuild_ReleaseVersion_LOG.log
set msBuildDir=

XCOPY .\MyProject\Bin\Release\*.* .\BuildResults\
```

That way, you remove a directory (just to make sure you get a super clean build), create it, build the solution/project and then copy the results of the build to the fresh directory.

Super fresh, every time. And if the build blows up, the \BuildResults directory is empty.

And a subtle little indicator, the datetime of the \BuildResults directory is the last time you built (or tried to build) the solution/project.  Subtle, but sometimes helpful.

Comment: using Visual Studio Command Prompt, i was able to build my solution without creating .bat file. `MSBuild "MySolution.sln" /P:Configuration=Debug`

Comment: granadaCoder actually .bat file is awesome, therefore dont have to keep going to Visual Studio Command Prompt. also nice to have that log file. thanks

Comment: Once you start doing it this way, you usually don't go back.  One time setup, repeatable results.

Comment: lol if Build Blows up!!! watch out that build is very unstable... anyway thanks again for update.

Comment: another useful setting is `/t:Clean,Build` this will clean up and rebuild `msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Clean,Build`

Comment: Nice find on the Clean and Build !

Comment: I get errors when building this way, but building in visual studio works fine. What gives?

Comment: Do you have nuget packages?  If so, manually run a "nuget restore MySolution.sln" before building.  You can get nuget.exe from https://dist.nuget.org/index.html.  If its not nuget, then you need to look at the log file and figure out specific errors.  And probably post a new question about specific errors.

Comment: This is really great info, except that the "super clean" build part doesn't make sense. If you're building to the same `bin/Release` folder, but never deleting it, how does copying it to a different folder make it cleaner?

Comment: I added  RD .\MyProject\Bin\Release\  /S /Q  to the answer to address that.  Good point, thanks,.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe with this command:

```
  >> devenv myproject.sln /Build "Release|x86"
```

You can find devenv in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" path.

Comment: Using Visual Studio Command Prompt (Developer Command Prompt) no need to look for the path of the devenv.exe

Answer (score 9):

I used a modification of the answer by @granadaCoder above.

For .NET version 4.5 onwards, there is no corresponding build directory in

> %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

and using MSBuild for an older framework will not let you compile newer constructs like interpolated strings.

TO get around this, you'll need to install the latest `MS Build Tools` (2015 currently) and use `MSBuild.exe` in

> %programfiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

Comment: Thanks for keeping the answer up to date........with the change in location for msbuild.exe.

Comment: You also have to put `%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe` in double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Install the .NET SDK and use the MsBuild.exe command line tool. It's what Visual Studio uses when you build a project or solution.

Comment: Not necessarily. At least Visual Studio is able to build some project types that MSBuild cannot (setup projects, for example). You can call `devenv` to compile, though.

Comment: I believe msbuild.exe comes with the ~~Framework~~ (only) install, not the ~SDK. See http://www.csharp411.com/where-to-find-msbuild-exe/ .  It started to be included with 2.0 and on.  Aka, the SDK install may be unnecessary.

Comment: Joey is correct, msbuild.exe will build ~most applications.  Here is an example I've run across where msbuild.exe will NOT work.  The ".rulep" is a custom IBM application (project) type and must be built using devenv.exe     http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14402518&tstart=0

Comment: i installed the .net sdk but the environment variable is still not registering when I type msbuild or msbuild.exe in the cmd

Comment: Did you look at or try the .bat file solution listed later in this post?

Comment: @user708774 You might need to restart your shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

I've tried this in 7.0 .net sdk.

> G:\Other\Sonarr\src>dotnet --version
> 7.0.107
> G:\Other\Sonarr\src>dotnet build
> MSBuild version 17.4.4+8e9cb2952 for .NET
> ...
> ...
> 已成功生成。  *In English, build successfully.*

Code: https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr.git