# use a batch file to execute msbuild project

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

I'm an intern and have created an msbuild project that builds all of the .csproj files in the repository. Now I have to create a batch file that calls the msbuild.csproj I made and execute it on a daily schedule (say every day at 12:00pm). I don't know how to make a batch file and need some help getting started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place this in a .bat file:

```
set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5    
REM perhaps you need a different framework? %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319


call %msBuildDir%\msbuild /target:AllTargetsWrapper "MySolutionOrCsProj.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug;FavoriteFood=Twix /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=ZZZZZMSBuildSetupAndBuildAllTargetsWrapper_Debug.log

set msBuildDir=
```

You'll have to adjust the target name.

Wait, I just remembered I answered this before in more detail.
See:

[Build Visual Studio project through the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669765/build-visual-studio-project-through-the-command-line/5669820#5669820)

Comment: ooc why would he set msBuildDir 2x? it would be overwritten. Did you mean to put an IF EXIST in front?

Comment: He (or she) didn't mention the framework he (or she) is using.  You only need one "setter", but I was drawing attention that one has to match up the FW version.

Comment: Ahh, If you change this to say IF EXIST %WINDIR%\.\.\v3.5 set msBuildDir= etc... do that first, that way it will use the latest version of .NETFW

Comment: Just because one has the latest FW installed, does not mean that is the FW to use to build the .sln file.  I have framework 4.5 installed, BUT, most of the time I am using FW 4.0 to build the projects.

Comment: Ok, glad it helped.  Don't forget you have the power to mark as "correct answer" and/or upvote the response.  Thanks.

Comment: @Beginners_Luck I agree, consider marking this as "Correct" if this has solved your answer

Comment: @granadaCoder you are correct, however in this particular case wouldn't FW 3.5 be preferred over 2.0?

Comment: Since 3.5 and 3.0 are more "add ons" to 2.0, yeah that might make sense.  But building with \v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe simply because "it exists" (and you have a .sln/.csproj in VS2008 format).......isn't sound IMHO.

Comment: I agree, but we didn't have /v4.0.30319 included :)