# Running MSBuild from command prompt

Tags: python, msbuild, command-prompt

If I open up Command Prompt, and type msbuild, or /msbuild followed by a path file, It says that

`'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch 
    file.`'

However, when I run the same lines in visual studios command prompt it works.. Anybody know why this is?

Here is my python script to run MSBuild through the command prompt

```
import subprocess
filename="C:\Users\bb\Documents\bb\Code\VisualStudio\tree.ProEAPI.UnitTests\tree.ProEAPI.UnitTests.vbproj"
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe', filename], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line,
retval = p.wait()
```

Comment: Here is a "bat" method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669765/build-visual-studio-project-through-the-command-line/5669820#5669820

Answer (score 5):

When you launch a Visual Studio command prompt, it adds some additional locations to the 'path' environment variable - this happens to include the location of MSBuild.

Interesting side note - you can use the 'where' command in batch to find the path of an application. For example, running 'where msbuild' in the Visual Studio command line outputs this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>where msbuild
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
```

But in the standard command prompt, outputs this:

```
C:\Users\stephen.edmonds>where msbuild
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

You can view the current value of the path environment variable using the command 'set path'

Comment: When I add the whole filepath to MSBuild.exe directly then add the file path in the command prompt it works. However when i duplicate the same thing into my python script it does not work still it spits out the same message. I'll add an edit of my python code.

Answer (score 1):

Because your command pompt is missing the location of the msbuild.exe from its path environmental variable. Usually C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 for .net 4. try setting it in your computer management console or at the command prompt:

```
set path=%path%;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
```

then try msbuild again.