# MSBuild-ing a VB Project with an InstallShield

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, installshield

I'm trying to create a MSBuild script that could build a VB project and an InstallShield Setup project.

Here's a BuildAll.XML file as the MSBuild script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="D:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1.vbproj" />
    <MSBuild Projects="D:\WindowsApplication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Running this command on the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012.

```
msbuild.exe D:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\BuildAll.xml /t:Build
```

The first MSBuild for the WindowApplication1.vbproc completes the build, but when the MSBuild would try to build the Setup1.isproj it fails.

Here's the warning and error:

> "D:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\BuildAll.xml" (Build
>   target) ( 1) -> "D:\WindowsApplication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj" (default
>   target) (3) -> (Build target) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.target s :
>   warning : -7235: InstallShield could not create the software
>   identification  tag because the Tag Creator ID setting in the General
>   Information view is empt y.
>   [D:\WindowsApplication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj]   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.target s :
>   warning : -1527: No files are included in the project. [D:\WindowsAppl
>   ication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj]
>
> "D:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\BuildAll.xml" (Build
>   target) ( 1) -> "D:\WindowsApplication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj" (default
>   target) (3) -> (Build target) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.target s(108,3):
>   error : No outputs for project "WindowsApplication1" were provided, b
>   ut the installation project references
>   "WindowsApplication1.ContentFiles". [D:\
>   \WindowsApplication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj]   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.target s(108,3):
>   error : No outputs for project "WindowsApplication1" were provided, b
>   ut the installation project references "WindowsApplication1.Built".
>   [D:\WindowsApplication1\Setup1\Setup1.isproj]

The Setup1 Project has two Application Files:

- WindowsApplication1.ContentFiles
- WindowsApplication1.PrimaryOutput

But when I use the **Build > Build Solution** on the Visual Studio 2012, it works fine. It produces the Setup.exe.

How can I make my BuildAll.xml make the same building process with the Visual Studio's Build Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669765/build-visual-studio-project-through-the-command-line/5669820#5669820).

I should have built the entire solution rather than per project

Here's the correct script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="D:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1.sln" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```