# Compile a .NET Core project to .exe file instead of .dll file

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm trying to create a C# application (`.cs` files). Since I'm using **Visual Studio Code**, I have to use the command line in order to compile the project, but when I launch **MSBuild**, it generates a `.dll` file.

> MSBuild version : 15.8.169.51996

This is my `.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="3.1.1">

      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Visual Studio project through the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669765/build-visual-studio-project-through-the-command-line)  see also **[Walkthrough: Use MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019)** from the online Docs

Comment: Thanks but msbuild is still compiling a .dll instead of an .exe. I think the problem is inside the .csproj . Any ideas?

Comment: You need to specify runtime, so that MSBuild know which executable to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Deployment in .NET Core

Because of you are using a `netcoreapp`, officially called **.NET Core**, things are little different here.

**.NET Core** is a cross platform framework. It's mean that software you wrote will execute in both Windows, Linux and OSX. Have you seen an `.exe` running on Linux? Not in the usual way..

#### After you understand this, you have several options:

1. Use the `.dll` as expected. With . NET Core, you run your `.dll` by the command `dotnet your.dll`.
2. You can use the [SCD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) deployment and set the `RuntimeIdentifier` to be `win10-x64`.
3. You can upgrade to **.NET Core sdk 2.2** (`netcoreapp2.2`) and use the [FDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-executables-fde) deployment.

Comment: With the `/p:PublishSingleFile=true` option you get a single exe file. Example: `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`