# Batch file to run after publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment

Is there a way to execute a batch file after publishing a web application i.e. after using the 'Publish' option.

I have read a few other questions on here which suggest the following:

1) Add AfterPublish attribute to the Project file:

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" >
    <Exec Command="echo Post-PUBLISH event: Active configuration is: $(ConfigurationName)" />
</Target>
```

This does not seem to work.  Is this only relevant to Visual Studio 2010?

2) Add the batch file location to the AfterBuild Text box as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

After Build runs before the publish so this will not work.  How can I do this in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776635/replicate-vs2008-publish-web-site-from-command-line) states:

> The following command duplicates the Publish Web Site dialog with default settings.
>
> Command for Publish Web Site with Default Settings
>
> ```
> aspnet_compiler -nologo -v / -p "C:\WebSite1" -u "C:\TargetPath"
> ```

So you can do as following:

1) Read the above post and try to build a bat file with the compilation/publish command.

2) Within that bat file, after compiling/publishin the website with the previous command, add the batch commands you want to execute.

Hope this helps you